# Substract navigation bar subtitle's value with cell's detail value

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am building a simple budget app, which will allow me to add specified budget and then considering my added expenses, calculate my actual outcome.
In Details Controller: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQdqK.png), I want to be able to grab subtitle value from navigation bar, subtract it with value from cell's detailLabel and finally present in footer's label Wallet Balance. So far, I have been struggling with retrieving subtitle's value and doing calculation.

Here is my Main Controller: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JphUw.png), which is used to send data forward to Details Controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? AddBudgetViewController {
        destinationViewController.delegate = self
    }

    // pass cell's label to detailVC
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as? BudgetDetailsViewController
    let cell = sender as? BudgetCell
    destinationVC?.navigationItem.setTitle(title:(cell?.budgetNameLabel.text?.capitalized)!, subtitle:(cell?.detailTextLabel?.text)!)
}
```

*AddBudgetViewController* : using delegation to pass data back to main controller

```
 protocol BudgetDelegate: class {
    func enteredBudgetData(info: String, info2: String)
}

 class AddBudgetViewController: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: BudgetDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var budgetName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var budgetAmount: UITextField!

//
@IBAction func saveContent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if ((budgetName.text?.isEmpty)! && (budgetAmount.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    } else {
        delegate?.enteredBudgetData(info: budgetName.text!, info2: budgetAmount.text!)
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

*Using didSelectRowAt* instead segue method above

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //
    let budget = self.budget[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name:"BudgetList", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsController") as! BudgetDetailsViewController
    viewController.budgets = budget

    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

*DetailsController*

```
class BudgetDetailsViewController: UITableViewController, ExpenseDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var walletBalance: UILabel!
var expense = [Expense]()
var budgets: Budget! {
    didSet {
        if isViewLoaded {
            calculateWalletBudget(budget:, expense:)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than passing labels text to the detail view controller, create a n object that holds all the data you need and pass back and forth to set the navigation title and texts in labels.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now I need to grab those values and calculate them to get result. Can I get any hints for that?

Comment: I'm making a sample code for you. Just Let me know where I can send the code. I will take 30 min.

Comment: HMHero, can u post it on github? Really appreciating your input.

Comment: https://github.com/hwanmoon/StackOverflow. let me know if you have any question

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot. Will check this tomorrow.

Comment: @HMHero Hey, it has been a while and I recently got time to go back to this little project of mine. I have made changes according to your suggestions, but cannot fix issue with the wallet balance. Generally, balance is not calculated properly (refreshed) and I am losing data when leaving detailsVC. You can find my project here: https://github.com/kowalskiy/BudgetList, I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: I will take a look at later today when I have break.

Comment: I fixed the issues. Let me know how you want to get my changes.

Comment: @HMHero I have added you as collaborator on github. Let me know if you can post something.

Comment: I push a new branch. Just made some change based on what I think it should be right.

Comment: @HMHero I have just one question considering iteration of index and  existingBudget. Could explain shortly what is happening there? Posted comment on github.

Comment: a comment added.